# Transforming Points on a scaled HTML Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, angular, html5-canvas

I'm working on a tool for drawing bounding boxes on images using the Canvas and Angular. Up until this point I have it working that, when using the mouse scroll wheel at a certain point, the canvas zooms to that point. However, this seems to cause difficulties when trying to draw bounding boxes when also zoomed in. I'm thinking there has to be a transformation for the new bounding box but I think a partial problem is the fact that the origin changes with mouse movements. My component for initializing the image, zooming to a mouse point, and drawing a bounding box at a certain coordinate currently looks like this.

```
export class BoxComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  public defaultFile = "assets/KWT_2014-09-06_BGisborne_PachenaPoint_5128.JPG"
  private maxCanvasWidth = 1600;
  private maxCanvasHeight = 800;
  private zoomLevel = 0;
  private zooms = 0;
  private scale = 1;
  private originX = 0;
  private originY = 0;
  private zoomFactor = 1;
  private visibleWidth = this.maxCanvasWidth;
  private visibleHeight = this.maxCanvasHeight;

  public id = 1000;
  public panModeActive = true;
  public boxModeActive = false;
  public boxes: Array<Box> = [];
  public newBox: Box | undefined = undefined;
  private ctx: any = undefined;

  @ViewChild("canvasElement", {static: false}) canvas: ElementRef | undefined;
  @ViewChild("imageElement", {static: false}) img: ElementRef | undefined;
  
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    if (this.canvas !== undefined && this.img !== undefined) {
      const canvas = this.canvas.nativeElement;
      this.ctx = this.canvas.nativeElement.getContext('2d');
      const image = this.img.nativeElement
      image.addEventListener("load", (e: any) => {
        canvas.width = this.maxCanvasWidth;
        canvas.height = this.maxCanvasHeight;

        this.ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this.maxCanvasWidth, this.maxCanvasHeight);
      })
    }
  }

  mouseZoom($event: any): void {
    $event.preventDefault();
    const x = $event.clientX - this.canvas!.nativeElement.offsetLeft;
    const y = $event.clientY - this.canvas!.nativeElement.offsetTop; 
    const scroll = $event.deltaY < 0 ? 1 : -1;
    this.zoom(x, y, scroll, $event);
  }

  zoom(x: number, y: number, factor: number, $event: any) {
    const zoomIntensity = 0.1;
    const zoom = Math.exp(factor * zoomIntensity);
    this.zoomFactor = zoom;
    this.ctx.translate(this.originX, this.originY);
    this.originX -= x / (this.scale * zoom) - x / this.scale;
    this.originY -= y / (this.scale * zoom) - y / this.scale;
    this.ctx.scale(zoom, zoom);
    this.ctx.translate(-this.originX, -this.originY);
    this.scale *= zoom;
    this.visibleWidth = this.maxCanvasWidth / this.scale;
    this.visibleHeight = this.maxCanvasHeight / this.scale;
  }


  drawRectangle($event: any) {
    this.ctx.strokeStyle = "white";
    this.ctx.lineWidth = 2
    const x = $event.clientX - this.canvas!.nativeElement.offsetLeft;
    const y = $event.clientY - this.canvas!.nativeElement.offsetTop;
    const w = 100;
    const h = 100;

    this.ctx.strokeRect(x, y, w, h);
  }
}
```

As I said, the zooming seems to work fine. But, depending on there the mouse was when zooming in, the x and y coordinates for the box are way off of what was clicked. This seems to be dependent on the updated origin because, for example, attempting to create a box to the right of the updated origin causes the created box to be much further right than expected.

I'm sure there is a simple fix here but playing around with the transform and different measurements has so far not been successful.

Answer (score 1):

As I thought, the answer was fairly simple. The scale as well as the origin obviously play a role. So you have to scale and transform the mouse clicks to the correct position:

```
getMouseXY($event: any) {
    return [
      ($event.x - this.canvas!.nativeElement.offsetLeft) / Math.exp(this.zooms * this.zoomIntensity) + this.originX,
      ($event.y - this.canvas!.nativeElement.offsetTop) / Math.exp(this.zooms * this.zoomIntensity) + this.originY]
  }
```

where `this.zooms` is an integer determining how many times the user has zoomed in or out. (+1 for zoom in, -1 for zoom out) and `this.zoomIntensity = 0.1`